# Xamarin get API result when status code is 500

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my xamarin.forms app I am consuming a simple web API. The API method is `POST`. I am passing some credentials and the API will fetch if there is valid data against the passed parameters.

When the passed parameters is valid the result data look like this

```
{
    "results": {
        "break_id": 40,
        "person_id": 48,     
    },
    "success": true
}
```

When the parameters is invalid, the API result will look like this

```
{
    "message": "Please enter correct details.",
    "success": false
}
```

When we check these APIs on Postman, the successfull result shows status Code `200`. When failed result will show with status code `500`.

I am parsing the API like this.

```
 private HttpRequestMessage req;    
    var jsonObtained = "";
    string stringObtained = "";
    var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress };
    T resultObject;                            
 
   try
    {
             req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, apiurl);
             client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
             new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", Settings.AuthToken);
             req.Content = new StringContent(postdata, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
             Task<string> task = Task.Run(async () => await Threading(client, req));
             task.Wait();
             stringObtained = task.Result;
             jsonObtained = Regex.Unescape(stringObtained);  
    
             var resultJSON = jsonObtained;
    
             resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(resultJSON);
    }
    
    Catch(Exception ex)
    {
        
    }
```

The problem is when result is faliure, The exception will thrown with `500 Internal Server Error`. Can I get the `success` and `message` values in the result? Currently it will throw the exception at the line

```
 req.Content = new StringContent(postdata, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

How can I solve this? Should the status code must be `200` for failed result also? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How does it return the "message" and "success"? If you could get the json from the code, put the code in the catch statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is server side not related to xamarin, see reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500)

I'd say to add a breakpoint on your httpClient creation and confirm the baseaddress your are making the request to. If you have access to the API being used make sure that the request is reaching the handler on the server side as well and debug what's happening internally

Comment: Hi Thanks. The message parameter is correct. Thats what expected. But the status code changed. I thought that we can get the message parameter even if the status code  is 500

Comment: No, the server is returning an internal error so there's no way for him to return the expected object